# jquery video reset on dialog close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 inline videos and popup on the same page with a video embedded. Whenever I open the popup and play the video and then I close the dialog box the video should be reset instead of staying paused in the same position where I closed it when I open the dialog again.

```
var activeDialog = com.gsk.mt.getActiveDialog();// gets active dialog id        
if (activeDialog !== null && !activeDialog.hasClass("quickLinkDialog") && activeDialog.hasClass("videoDialog")) {
  $('video').each(function() {                  
    $(this).get(0).pause();
    $(this).get(0).currentTime = 0;                 
  });
}
```

For this code, all the videos are being reset as I'm using each function. How can reset only the video in the popup? Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to traverse the DOM to find the `video` elements within the dialog which was closed. Assuming that `activeDialog` is a jQuery object, which it would appear to be given your use of `hasClass()`, then you can simply use `find()`, like this:

```
var activeDialog = com.gsk.mt.getActiveDialog();    if (activeDialog !== null && !activeDialog.hasClass("quickLinkDialog") && activeDialog.hasClass("videoDialog")) {
  activeDialog.find('video').each(function() {                    
    this.pause();
    this.currentTime = 0;                 
  }); 
}
```

Also note the use of `this` over `$(this).get(0)` to change the video's properties.